# Phenomena of gerbes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, examples, stacks, gerbes

> What is your favourite example of **Gerbes**?

I would like to know *Where do we find Gerbes in "nature"?*

The examples could vary from String theory to Galois theory. For example my favourite examples of Gerbes are [Nori fundamental gerbe](https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.1260), and that Tannakian categories could be described, in cohomological terms, by the gerbe of its fibre functors. What is yours?

Comment: I know little about gerbes, but I like how they appear naturally in classical field theory.

Comment: If you are happy with _bundle_ gerbes, which are nothing more than a choice of presentation of a gerbe on the category of (smooth) manifolds by a Lie groupoid, then there are plenty of examples: https://scholar.google.com.au/scholar?hl=en&q=bundle+gerbes&btnG=&as_sdt=1%2C5&as_sdtp= My favourite would be the String group on a compact, simple, simply-connected Lie group (note that it appears this really doesn't exist in the algebraic world)

Comment: Soient $X$un U-topos et $G$ un groupe de $X$. Le $X$-Champ $MOR_X(X, B_G)$ est un gerbe, anti-équivalente à celle des $G$-torseurs de $X$.

Comment: every codimension two algebraic cycle on a smooth variety produces a K2-gerbe, analogous to a divisor producing a line bundle.

Comment: @guest Could you elaborate please? Or give a reference?

Comment: @ მამუკა ჯიბლაძე :  just as the "set" of local defining equations for a divisor form a $\mathbb G_m$-torsor, the local defining equations of a codimension two variety form a K2-gerbe..see https://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/documenta/vol-21/35.html

Comment: @guest After a year :) - I like this example very much! Would you add an answer with it?

Answer (score 30):

At least when the group $G$ is discrete, and when the base is a topological space (as opposed to e.g. a scheme), I would like to advertise the fact that:

> a $G$-gerbe is the same thing as a fibration whose fiber is $BG$ (the latter is the classifying space of $G$, also known as $K(G,1)$).

As an example, by taking $G=\mathbb Z$, we learn that an $S^1$-bundle is the same thing as a $\mathbb Z$-gerbe.

So the Hopf fibration $S^1 \to S^3 \to S^2$ is a $\mathbb Z$-gerbe over $S^2$.

Comment: Another way of saying the same thing that works over any site is that a gerbe is just a sheaf of spaces (groupoids) that is locally equivalent to a sheaf of the form $BG$ for $G$ a sheaf of groups.

Answer (score 18):

You can get a lot of examples by *dimension shifting*. Namely, consider any exact sequence of groups $$1\to K\to G \to H\to 1 \; .$$ Fix a $H$-torsor $T$. The stack $\mathcal G_T$ of liftings of the structure group of $T$ to $G$ is clearly a gerbe (the objects are pairs $(T',\alpha)$, where $T'$ is a $G$-torsor and $\alpha : T'\times^G H \simeq T$ is an isomorphism). A more compact description as a quotient stack : $\mathcal G_T=[T/G]$. The band of $\mathcal G_T$ is of course (the band of) $K$.

Special instances of this construction :

- the gerbe of $n$-th roots of an invertible sheaf (sometimes called Chern gerbe modulo $n$),
- from Brauer theory : to any $\operatorname{PSL}_n$-torsor you can associate a $\mathbb G_m$-gerbe. This is probably my favourite example.

Comment: This is a nice construction; for instance, applied to the exponential sequence, it shows that the first Chern class $c_1(L) \in H^2(X, \mathbb Z)$ of a line bundle $L$ over a complex algebraic variety $X$ classifies the $\mathbb Z$-gerbe of obstructions to lifting $L$ (viewed as a $\mathcal O^*_{an}$-torsor) to a $\mathcal O_{an}$-torsor.

Answer (score 10):

The following is a fancy way of saying that every elliptic curve contains a copy of $\mathbb Z/2$ in its automorphism group:

> The moduli stack of elliptic curves is a $\mathbb Z/2$-gerbe over some other Deligne-Mumford stack (which doesn't seem to have a name).

Comment: Uninteresting remark: The DM stack is (by definition) "the rigidification of the moduli stack of elliptic curves with respect to the flat normal subgroup $\{\pm 1\}$ of the inertia stack". That's a nice name right?

Comment: I believe this other moduli stack is the moduli stack of genus 0 modular curves with 4 marked points, one unlabeld and three labeled.

Comment: If you consider the Deligne-Mumford compactifications instead, then the statement is that the orbifold projective line $\mathbb P(4,6)$ is a $\mathbb Z/2$-gerbe over the orbifold projective line $\mathbb P(2,3)$.

Comment: @Dan. Yes, over $\mathbb C$, that's a description of those stacks. But my statement also holds over $\mathbb Q$. Over rings of positive characteristic (e.g. characteristic two), I'm not sure whether the action of $\mathbb Z/2$ on an elliptic curve is always faithful. Is it always faithful?

Comment: Yes, it's always faithful. But you're right: you need to invert the primes 2 and 3 to get the isomorphism $\overline M_{1,1} \cong \mathbb P(4,6)$.

Answer (score 5):

My favorite one, in the sense that I am trying to really understand it for many years, is the determinantal gerbe of a locally linearly compact vector space, as described by Kapranov in "[Semiinfinite symmetric powers](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0107089)".

I am making this Community Wiki since I don't really understand well this fascinating thing, so if anybody could make this answer better it would be great.

For a field $k$ and a topological vector space $V$ with certain property (linear local compactness, to be more precise, see below), he associates the $\textit{determinantal gerbe}$ $\operatorname{Det}(V)$. This is a $k^*$-gerbe. Its objects are $\textit{determinantal theories}$ for $V$. A determinantal theory $\Delta$ assigns to each open subspace $U$ of $V$ a 1-dimensional space $\Delta(U)$, and to a pair of open subspaces $U_1\subseteq U_2$ with finite-dimensional quotient, an isomorphism
$$
\Delta_{U_1,U_2}:\Delta(U_1)\otimes\det(U_2/U_1)\to\Delta(U_2),
$$
where $\det$ of a finite-dimensional vector space is its highest exterior power.

These must satisfy a coherence condition
$$
\Delta(U_2,U_3)\circ\left(\Delta(U_1,U_2)\otimes\det(U_3/U_2)\right)=\Delta(U_1,U_3)\circ\det(U_1,U_2,U_3)
$$
for $U_1\subseteq U_2\subseteq U_3$, where $\det(U_1,U_2,U_3):\det(U_2/U_1)\otimes\det(U_3/U_2)\to\det(U_3/U_1)$ is the canonical map. Then $k^*$ acts on isomorphisms of determinantal theories and turns the groupoid of such isomorphisms into a $k^*$-gerbe.

This gerbe seems to be related to very important constructions, none of them I really understand well. As Kapranov and several other authors explain, it goes back to [Tate's thesis](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=ASENS_1968_4_1_1_149_0),
who used it to describe residues of differentials in terms of traces of operators on adelic spaces. Notable further works after that, to mention just the most striking ones, include "[The Infinite Wedge Representation and the Reciprocity Law for Algebraic Curves](https://books.google.com/books?hl=en&lr=&id=0UcECAAAQBAJ&oi=fnd&pg=PA171&dq=The+Infinite+Wedge+Representation+and+the+Reciprocity+Law+for+Algebraic+Curves&ots=O5WXTmy0Rz&sig=ycy0pVpVD_skOJKcjQ3R27EQG6c&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=The%20Infinite%20Wedge%20Representation%20and%20the%20Reciprocity%20Law%20for%20Algebraic%20Curves&f=false)" by Arbarello, de Concini and Kac (in "Theta Functions, Bowdoin 1987", PSPM 49 (1989), Part 1, 171-190), "[Central extensions and reciprocity laws](http://www.numdam.org/item?id=CTGDC_1997__38_3_193_0)" by Brylinski (Cah. Topol. Géom. Différ. Catégor., **38** (1997), 193-215), "[Infinite-Dimensional Vector Bundles
in Algebraic Geometry:
An Introduction](https://books.google.com/books?id=lS9GAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA263&dq=Infinite-Dimensional+Vector+Bundles+in+Algebraic+Geometry+An+Introduction&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=Infinite-Dimensional%20Vector%20Bundles%20in%20Algebraic%20Geometry%20An%20Introduction&f=false)" by Drinfeld (in "The Unity of Mathematics: In Honor of the Ninetieth Birthday of I.M. Gelfand", Birkhäuser Progress in Mathematics series **244** (2007), 263-304)

**Appendix** - definition of linear local compactness.

A linearly compact vector space over a field $k$ is a Hausdorff topological vector space $V$ that has a base of neighborhoods of $0$ consisting of vector subspaces and closed affine subspaces have finite intersection property. It is linearly locally compact if it has a $0$-neighborhood base consisting of linearly compact subspaces.

Answer (score 4):

A typical example from deformation theory : fix $i:X_0\to X$ of first order thickening  defined by a square zero ideal $\mathcal I$, and let $\mathcal E_0$ be a locally free sheaf of finite rank on $X_0$. Then the stack of deformations of  ${\mathcal E_0}$ to $X$ is a gerbe on $X_0$ banded by $\mathcal I\otimes \operatorname{End(}\mathcal E_0)$.

It is neutral if and only if the deformation problem is unobstructed, and in this case the stack of deformations is isomorphic, after choice of a lifting, to 
 $B\left( \mathcal I\otimes \operatorname{End}(\mathcal E_0\right))$.

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathscr{C}$ be a Tannakian category over $Spec(k)$. Then $FIB(\mathscr{C})$ is an affine gerbe over $Spec(k)$ in the fpqc topology. [1]

Let us consider Tannakian categories $\mathscr{C}$ over a field k, and for which there exists a $K$-valued fibre functor $x$, which values in some finite separable field extension $K$ of k. In this case, the corresponding gerbe $\mathscr{G} = FIB(\mathscr{C})$ of fibre functors on $\mathscr{C}$ is a gerbe over $Spec(k)$ in the étale topology. [2]

[1]: *Catégories Tannakiennes, P Deligne*, in the Grothendieck Festschrift II, Progr. Math. 87, Birkhäuser, Boston, 1990, pp. 111-195.

[2]: *Tannakian categories, L Breen*, in Motives, Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics, 55, Providence, R.I.: American Mathematical Society, 1994.

Answer (score 3):

The [root gerbes](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0604458) $${^r}\sqrt{\mathscr{L}/X}$$ associated to a line bundle on a scheme (or stack) $X$

Comment: I've just read that this example also appears in Niels' answer below.

Answer (score 3):

If $\mathscr{M}$ is the moduli stack of mathematical objects $X$ of some specified kind such that $\mathrm{Aut}(X)$ always (naturally) contains a group (object) $G\subseteq\mathrm{Aut}(X)$, then $\mathscr{M}$ will be a $G$-gerbe over some other stack $\mathscr{M}^{\mathrm{rig},G}$. Examples of this include

- the moduli stack of elliptic curves: $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ (see André Henriques' answer)
- the moduli stack of hyperelliptic curves of a given genus: again $G=\mathbb{Z}/2$ (the "common" generator is naturally the hyperelliptic involution)
- the moduli stack of vector bundles: $G=\mathbb{G}_{\mathrm{m}}$
- ...

Answer (score 0):

The following is very nicely described by Malikov in Section 3 of "An Introduction to Algebras of Chiral Differential Operators" ("[Perspectives in Lie Theory](https://books.google.com/books?id=1zVCDwAAQBAJ)", pages 73 - 124).

For a smooth algebraic variety $X$ there is a gerbe $\mathscr{PL}_X$ of *Picard-Lie algebroids* over $X$. Objects of the groupoid $\mathscr{PL}_X(U)$ of its sections over an affine open $U=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ are Lie $A$-algebroids, i. e. Lie algebras equipped with an action on $A$ by derivations and with an $A$-module structure satisfying certain conditions; "Picard" means that another piece of the structure is an isomorphism of the kernel of the action with $A$.

The lien of $\mathscr{PL}_X$ is the sheaf complex $d:\Omega^1_X\to\Omega^{2,\mathrm{cl}}_X$ where $d$ is the de Rham differential. Roughly, this means two things:

1. one can twist a Picard-Lie algebroid by a de Rham 2-cocycle (i. e. by a closed 2-form) to
   obtain another one, and any two Picard-Lie algebroids are such
   twists of each other, in a way unique up to a coboundary (i. e. up to an exact form);
2. one can twist a morphism $f:L_1\to L_2$ of Picard-Lie
   algebroids by a de Rham 1-cochain whose coboundary twists $L_1$ into $L_2$ as in 1. above to obtain another morphism between
   them, and any two morphisms $L_1\to L_2$
   are such twists of each other in a unique way.

This gerbe has a global section (action of $\mathcal O_X\rtimes\mathcal T_X$ on $\mathcal O_X$) but is nevertheless very interesting, providing a prototype for building de Rham complexes on loop spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{F}$ be a sheaf of topological spaces on $X$.

Then, the map $U\mapsto \pi_1(\mathcal{F}(U))$ for $U\subseteq X$ open is a gerbe over $X$.

I learned this example from André Henriques‘s answer to one of my questions.

Please feel free to edit this to make it more clear and/or to give references.