# Phenomena of topos

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, ho.history-overview, topos-theory

These days I am wandering on a wild adventure in an incredible but intimidating land. Fortunately, I could find a guide to some animals of this land

[Phenomena of gerbes](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263832/phenomena-of-gerbes)

But someone said to me that this wild land was crowded with topos. I thought collecting examples of topos you found in nature would be a good idea for my stay here. So my question is

> What is your favorite example of (Grothendieck) topos?

I can start citing the simplest ones as examples. The *category of sheaves of sets on a topological space* (in particular the *category of sets*) and the *category of $G$-sets* (i.e. sets equipped with a left action of $G$).

It would be preferable if you give, along with the definition, a simple explanation of its context.

Comment: Your two examples are essentially all there is: any Grothendieck topos is equivalent to the topos of sheaves of sets on a localic groupoid, a mild generalization of topological groupoids.

Comment: Keeping only to Grothendieck toposes rules out a bunch of interesting examples, but its not clear what your motivation and goal is, though i imagine this is informing your restriction to that case. Can you say more? In any case, if this is a [big-list] example question, it should be CW-ised.

Comment: The premise of the question seems weird to me. This makes about as much sense as "what is your favourite topological space", to which anyone who actually works with topological spaces can never provide an answer.

Comment: Cmon', guys -- the category of sets is coke classic for topoi. After that I have no idea.

Comment: There’s a construction described in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/454393/5191) for “cheap nonstandard analysis”.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that @DmitriPavlov 's comment is true but far from obvious. It is a deep theorem of Joyal and Tierney, in their _An Extension of the Galois Theory of Grothendieck_.

Answer (score 5):

I like the example of the non-Grothendieck $\mathbf{Set}$-topos (i.e. there is a non-bounded geometric morphism to $\mathbf{Set}$) given by the category of continuous actions of a proper class-sized topological group. Since this is foundationally a bit subtle, either you take a Grothendieck universe, and work relative to that, or otherwise one can carefully write out a definition or even a characterisation of the underlying category without having to resort to having such data as a topology on a proper class. For instance, one could look at the axiomatisation of what it means for a topos to be the category of continuous actions of a topological group, but then remove the requirement for a generating set.

But other more ad-hoc constructions are sometimes possible. For example, if the topological group is the limit indexed by $\mathrm{ORD}$ of a sequence of open surjections between topological groups, then there's a very nice description in terms of a colimit of the underlying lex cocomplete categories of the continuous actions of these topological groups, and inverse image functors.

Answer (score 5):

Let $A$ be a commutative ring.  Let $\mathcal{E}$ be the category of finite étale $A$-algebras, i.e. those $A$-algebras $B$ such that

1. $B$ is finitely generated and projective as an $A$-module
2. The kernel $I$ of the multiplication map $\mu\colon B\otimes_AB\to B$ satisfies $I^2=I$.

Then $\mathcal{E}^{\text{op}}$ is an elementary boolean topos (but not a Grothendieck topos, as there are no infinite coproducts).  The standard way to prove this is by a long detour into algebraic geometry, but it is a nice example to do it more directly.  We can take $A$ to be a field or the ring of integers in a number field, and many facts of Galois theory and algebraic number theory have natural interpretations in terms of the corresponding topoi.

Comment: Presumably this is the topos of finite sets equipped with an action of the Galois groupoid?

Answer (score 4):

My favorite topos is a presheaf topos: the category of [simplicial sets](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/simplicial+set).

Answer (score 4):

Terence Tao's [cheap non-standard analysis](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/a-cheap-version-of-nonstandard-analysis/) can be interpreted as happening in a certain elementary topos, which I define here.
Amusingly, this construction can itself be interpreted as happening in the category of sheaves on a certain space, but I digress.

Let $A$ be a set and let $F$ be a filter of $P (A)$.
We define $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ to be the following category:

- The objects are indexed families of sets where the indexing set is in $F$.
- The morphisms $X \to Y$ are equivalence classes of indexed families of maps $f$ where:

  - The indexing set is in $F$.
  - For each index $a$ where $f_a$ is defined, $X_a$ and $Y_a$ are also defined and $f_a$ is a map $X_a \to Y_a$.
  - Two families are equivalent if the set of indices where they coincide is in $F$.
- Composition and identities are inherited from $\textbf{Set}$.

Then $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ is an elementary topos: finite limits and power objects can basically be constructed componentwise.
In particular, the diagonal embedding $\Delta : \textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Set}^A / F$ is a logical functor.
Since natural numbers objects are preserved by logical functors, it follows that $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ has a natural numbers object: $\Delta (\mathbb{N})$.
Furthermore, $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ is boolean and satisfies the external axiom of choice.
Thus, $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ satisfies the axioms of ETCS except possibly for well-pointedness.

It is not hard to see that the lattice of subobjects of $1$ in $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ is isomorphic to the boolean algebra $P (A) / F$.
In particular, if $F$ is not an ultrafilter, then $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ is not well-pointed: it will have subterminal objects that are neither $0$ nor $1$.
Conversely, if $F$ is an ultrafilter then $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ is well-pointed – so we obtain a non-standard model of ETCS.

In general, $\Delta : \textbf{Set} \to \textbf{Set}^A / F$ fails to have a right adjoint.
Indeed, if $F$ is any non-principal filter, then $\Delta (F)$ is not the coproduct of its standard elements.
Let $\mu_a : F \to 2$ be defined as follows:
$$\mu_a (B) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if } a \notin B \\
1 & \text{if } a \in B
\end{cases}$$
Then, for each $B \in F$, $\mu (B)$ is equal to $1$ as morphisms $\Delta (1) \to \Delta (2)$.
On the other hand, $\{ a \in A : \mu_a = 1 \} = \bigcap_{B \in F} B \notin F$, so $\mu$ is distinct from the constant $1$ as morphisms $\Delta (F) \to \Delta (2)$.
Hence, the standard elements $\Delta (1) \to \Delta (F)$ do *not* comprise a jointly epimorphic cocone and cannot be a coproduct cocone.

(I think $\textbf{Set}^A / F$ also fails to be cocomplete in general, but the argument escapes me.
Certainly this is so when $F$ is not closed under countable intersections – then $\Delta (\mathbb{N})$ fails to be the coproduct of its standard elements, but in an elementary topos, if the coproduct of countably many copies of $1$ exists, then the natural numbers object is the coproduct of the standard numerals.)